# Handling/queueing a Windows-Service restart to apply new changes

Tags: design, windows, software, configuration-management

I'm working on a project that has the purpose to execute tasks in intervals.

The tasks and it's properties can be configured through the Configuration Website. The data is being stored in the Configuration Database.
The Windows-Service loads all the data from the Configuration Database on startup and then executes the tasks correspondingly:

[image]

That means that I have to restart my service in order to apply new changes.
There are several problems that come along with it:

**1. **Handling the restart manually or automatically****

I could restart the service every time changes have been made, which could be a bit overkill. I could also give the user the "responsibility" to restart the service. My target group aren't some random clients, they're also Sysadmins so they know what to do. I'd still need to mention somehow that there are "unapplied" changes.

**2. Knowing when to restart**

There's no direct communication between my website and the service. Restarting whenever could mean that it'll stop the service while it's executing a task; obviously not good. I'd somehow need to queue the restart after all ongoing tasks have been finished but I don't know how to realize this in the first place.

Comment: Change your logic, so you can push "please update your config" and the service loads the new config without the need to restart.

Comment: The answers to all of these seem to be 'it depends' - I Would start by discussing with the users about their preferences -- there's a good chance that sysadmins will be contented with having some manual steps/instructions and controlling this themselves -- perhaps they'll be happy just to have a message appear on their UI to remind them and pointing them to the instructions.

Comment: There is no question here. Your post boils down to "I have done A. Therefore, B/C is now the case". Yep. Correct assessment. What's the question?

Comment: @MrZach Very good suggestion, I might need to look at Windows-Service communication more. Maybe also WCF, even though that might be a bit too much for my project

Comment: @BenCottrell I'll talk to them about it. Perhaps a dialog box that includes "Do you want to apply the changes now/ Do you want to restart the service?" will do it. But that might get on their nerves

Comment: @Flater My question(s) relate to the problems that I mentioned. Handling the restart manually, automatically or through communication, as Mr. Zach said. Also solving the problem of restarting the service while it might execute a task.

Comment: @Junes I think including the UX/Journey as part of that discussion would be a good idea too.  I personally avoid 'confirmation' popups;  in my experience, users are more likely to build a 'muscle memory' habit around confirmation popups, increasing the chance they accidentally choose a destructive option if they are prompted afterwards.  If the choice is displayed *before* they click (e.g. Checkbox/Radio buttons), defaulted to the non-destructive option, then the option is on their screen for longer, and they're somewhat less likely to hastily choose the destructive option by mistake.

Comment: Another consideration may be to look at the service itself and how feasible it might be to prevent restarts from being a destructive action - i.e. if a job is interrupted partway through, then consider whether there's any feasible way to either recover or invalidate the previous attempt and re-run the job.

Answer (score 1):

Other alternatives:

Polling (1)
Read the Task configuration from the database periodically.

Polling (2)
Poll a "flag" in the database that's set when the configuration is changed and, if that flag has changed, then re-read the Task configuration.

Pause/Resume
As well as Stop and Start, Windows Services respond to two *other* verbs, Pause and Resume.
You could use *these* to "signal" to the service to re-read the configuration (as part of the Resume processing).
(OK, it *has* been a while since I did this) but I seem to recall that a 'Pause'd Service *can* continue to run useful stuff, so you can Pause and Resume without killing the Service entirely.

Comment: 1: Could work however the downside of it is not being able to apply the changes "directly". It depends on how often I want to do it, however considering that changes are mostly being made in bigger time gaps, that might not be the perfect solution.

2:
That could work, but I need to hook up some sort of event, otherwise if I just read the database periodically I have the same problem as with polling 1.

I haven't thought about pausing yet. Seems like a good idea to do "OnPause" and "OnResume" events!